# Streaming JSON Algorithm - WITHOUT STACK

Tags: algorithm, streaming, stack

Is it possible to design a streaming JSON algorithm that writes JSON directly to a socket with the following properties:

```
* can only write to, but cannot delete or seek within the stream
* does not use either an IMPLICIT or explicit stack
* uses only a constant amount of memory stack depth no matter how deep the object nesting within the json
```

{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{"1":{...}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

Comment: No; this is not homework. I am writing a web application in ruby, but I do not want to use the to_json method

Comment: Why not? And why on earth do you have these absurd constraints?

Comment: Trying to have minimal state and minimal memory, especially when dealing with streaming data, is a good thing. Not at all absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer:  At least not in the general case.  If you could guarantee that the nesting has no branching, you could use a simple counter to close the braces at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point me to any computer science papers/ FORMAL LANGUAGE THEORY articles (e.g. context free grammars, BCNF) that shows that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

No, because you could use such a program to compress infinite amounts of memory into a finite space.

### Encoding implementation:

```
input = read('LIBRARY_OF_CONGRESS.tar.bz2')
input_binary = convert_to_binary(input)
json_opening = replace({'0':'[', '1':'{'}, input_binary)
your_program <INPUTPIPE >/dev/null
INPUTPIPE << json_opening
```

Execute the above program then clone virtual machine it is running on. That is your finite-space compressed version of the infinitely-large input data set. Then to decode...

### Decoding implementation:

```
set_output_pipe(your_program, OUTPUTPIPE)
INPUTPIPE << EOL
json_closing << OUTPUTPIPE
output_binary = replace({']':'0', '}':'1'}, reverse(json_closing))
output = convert_from_binary(output_binary)
write(output, 'LIBRARY_OF_CONGRESS-copy.tar.bz2')
```

And of course, all good code should have a test case...

### Test case:

```
bc 'LIBRARY_OF_CONGRESS.tar.bz2' 'LIBRARY_OF_CONGRESS-copy.tar.bz2'
```